# PostgreSQL select most common combination of two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need help with manipulating a table in PostgreSQL.

I have a table with three columns and more than 30k rows. Many of the values repeat themselves in the lines.

I must write a `SELECT` statement that outputs the **most frequent values** of the first column, the most frequent values of the second column and the most common combination of both columns. The whole thing must be grouped by the third column.

What I've tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT column1 AS " Most frequent1", COUNT(column1) AS "occurrence"
     FROM table_name
     GROUP BY column1
     ORDER BY occurrence DESC
     LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT column2 AS "Most frequent2", COUNT(column2) AS "occurrence"
     FROM table_name
     GROUP BY column2
     ORDER BY occurrence DESC
     LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT CONCAT(column1, column2) AS "kombiniert", COUNT(CONCAT(column1, column2)) AS "occurrence"
     FROM table_name
     GROUP BY kombiniert
     ORDER BY occurrence DESC
     LIMIT 1);
```

How can I group the whole thing by column3?

Is there a better method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is `MODE`, the statistical mode = the most frequent value.

```
SELECT
  column3,
  MODE() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column1) AS most_frequent_column1,
  MODE() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column2) AS most_frequent_column2,
  MODE() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column1 || column2) AS most_frequent_pair
FROM table_name
GROUP BY column3
ORDER BY column3;
```

Two points:

- `MODE` ignores nulls. If this is undesired, you must workaround this.
- Just glueing the two strings together may or may not be what you are looking for. 'AB' || CD' = ' ABCD'. 'A' || BCD' = ' ABCD'.

For the latter, please see a_horse_with_no_name's comments below. `MODE() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY (column1, column2))` perfectly solves the ambiguous pairs issue.

Comment: You can use `(ORDER BY (column1, column2))` to avoid treating `AB, CD` the same as `ABC, D` - which also makes this work with _any_ data type, not just strings

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: No. There must only be one argument in the `ORDER BY` clause of `MODE`, because that is the expression we want the statistical mode for. (Yes, that's a weird syntax. I don't know why they didn't simply make this `MODE(expression)`).  As to treating AB, CD and ABC, D as the same value: Yes, I mentioned this in my answer. This is how the OP concatenated the strings and I mentioned that this may be undesired.

Comment: `(column1, column2)` **is** one expression - an anonymous "row type" https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3b5d9543045bc687dc011cd3e3d602ad

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Sorry, you are right of course.

Answer (score 2):

The most common value is called the *mode* in statistics.  This should return the three modes that you are looking for:

```
select col3,
       max(col1_cnt), max(case when seqnum_1 then col1 end),
       max(col2_cnt), max(case when seqnum_2 then col2 end),
       max(col12_cnt), max(case when seqnum_12 then col1 || ':' || col2 end)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col3 order by col1_cnt desc) as seqnum_1,
             row_number() over (partition by col3 order by col2_cnt desc) as seqnum_2,
             row_number() over (partition by col3 order by col12_cnt desc) as seqnum_12
      from (select col1, col2, col3, count(*) as cnt,
                   sum(count(*)) over (partition by col1) as col1_cnt,
                   sum(count(*)) over (partition by col2) as col2_cnt,
                   sum(count(*)) over (partition by col1, col2) as col1_col2_cnt
            from t
            group by col1, col2, col3
           ) t
     ) t
group by col3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you want to get the mode of two columns you can use the sum operator. Something like this:

```
MODE() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY (col1 + col2)) as mode_col_1_and_2
```

EDITED: After reading the comments and a lot of testing, I regret of this answer. @a_horse_with_no_name came with the right way:

```
MODE() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY (col1, col2)) as mode_col_1_and_2
```

Comment: This is inferior to the anonymous row type solution in the accepted answer and suffers from the same issues as normal concatenation.  Replace the `+` with a `,` to convert the argument type and do it right.